# How to write contents of an array to a text file? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, text

I'm trying to write the contents of an array to a text file.  I've created the file, assigned text boxes to the array (not sure if correctly).  Now I want to write the contents of the array to a text file.  The streamwriter part is where I'm stuck at the bottom.  Not sure of the syntax.

```
if ((!File.Exists("scores.txt"))) //Checking if scores.txt exists or not
{
    FileStream fs = File.Create("scores.txt"); //Creates Scores.txt
    fs.Close(); //Closes file stream
}
List<double> scoreArray = new List<double>();
TextBox[] textBoxes = { week1Box, week2Box, week3Box, week4Box, week5Box, week6Box, week7Box, week8Box, week9Box, week10Box, week11Box, week12Box, week13Box };

for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    scoreArray.Add(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxes[i].Text));
}
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("scores.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("scores.txt",
    textBoxes.Select(tb => (double.Parse(tb.Text)).ToString()));
```

Comment: Love this. No hassling with opening and closing files or creating stream writers, etc.  Just a one-liner that works.

Answer (score 6):

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open("scores.txt"))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    scoreArray.ForEach(r=>sw.WriteLine(r));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to write to the file before you close it... after the `FileStream fs = File.Create("scores.txt");` line of code.

You may also want to use a `using` for that.
Like this:

```
if ((!File.Exists("scores.txt"))) //Checking if scores.txt exists or not
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create("scores.txt")) //Creates Scores.txt
        {
            // Write to the file here!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `List` to an array then write the array to a textfile

```
double[] myArray = scoreArray.ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines("scores.txt",
  Array.ConvertAll(myArray, x => x.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to resolve your issue

Form.Close();

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a more in-depth explanation for why it does so.